# GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER missing on iOS OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am porting my engine to iOS and I got an error

```
'GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER' undefined
```

I am using iOS 8 SDK and OpenGL 3.0; Device is iPhone 5s.
Is there any alternative to this? Or how can I access geometry shader stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no geometry shaders in OpenGL ES, neither in 3.0 nor in 3.1.

There is an [extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_geometry_shader.txt), which is based on ES 3.1. Since iOS does not support 3.1 at this point, the extension is of course not available on iOS.

Alternatives? If you really need geometry shaders, Android based devices are always an option. :) Geometry shaders are part of the Android Extension Pack for ES 3.1, which is a selection of extensions that Google encourages device vendors to support.

---

Update: Geometry shaders are standard in ES 3.2. That does not help on iOS, though, since it still does not support anything higher than ES 3.0.

Comment: Oh well, I understand now, I hope Apple will add this extension somehow.